# Binary and decimal numbers in array

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to make an loop, which will generate 7 digits (0 or 1), making a binary number and transform it into decimal number. Everything in array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < licznpop; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
           if (rnd.nextBoolean()== true){ 
                 T[i][j]=1; T[i][8]+=1*2^(7-j);
           } else{
                 T[i][j]=0; T[i][8]+=0*2^(7-j);
           }

        System.out.print(T[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println(); 
}
```

licznpop is 10, so its generating 10 binaries numbers, but there is something wrong with decimals, it's almost always numbers between 20 and 30.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Where is `T` and `licznpop` in the code initialized?

Comment: `^` means XOR in Java, C, C++, C# etc. You might have intended `T[i][8] += 1 << (7 - j)` BTW Adding 0 is the same as doing nothing.

Comment: Few lines ealier, it's basically whole code

Comment: `if (x == true) `is the same as `if (x)`

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense, thank you very much